# How can i increment the counter?

Tags: sql-server-2005-express

At the registration time i wanted if side is left then my left count will increment and side is Right then my right is increment and both side is filled then their sponcor will increment... How can i do this????

HERE i wanted to increment the my counter but it is not working propperly always counter show me null...., please tell me where m wrong.???

```
DECLARE @regid int
SET @regid=@@IDENTITY
DECLARE @RegistrationCode varchar(100)
DECLARE registrationcodeCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT [dbo].[RegistrationCode] 
(
   'P4U',@fname,@mname,@lname,'000',@regid,'34',@dob
)
   OPEN registrationcodeCursor
   FETCH FROM registrationcodeCursor INTO @RegistrationCode
   CLOSE registrationcodeCursor
   DEALLOCATE registrationcodeCursor

UPDATE Registration_Master
SET regCode=@RegistrationCode
WHERE registrationid=@regid

DECLARE @regid1 int
SET @regid1=@@IDENTITY
DECLARE @usernm varchar(50)
DECLARE usernameCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT [dbo].[fullusername]
(
    @fname,' ',@mname,' ',@lname
)
OPEN usernameCursor
FETCH FROM usernameCursor INTO @usernm
CLOSE usernameCursor
DEALLOCATE usernameCursor

UPDATE Registration_Master
SET username=@usernm
WHERE registrationid=@regid1

--Pair Matching
SET @count_mem=0
WHILE(@sponcorid!=NULL)

BEGIN
    IF(@regCode !=NULL)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @countl int
        IF(@side ='LEFT')
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Registration_Master
            SET @count_mem=@count_mem+1
            WHERE regCode=@regCode AND side='LEFT' AND count_mem=@count_mem

        END
        DECLARE @countr int
        IF(@side='RIGHT')
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Registration_Master
            SET @count_mem=@count_mem+1
            WHERE regCode=@regCode AND side='RIGHT' AND count_mem=@count_mem
        END
        IF(@countl=@countr)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Registration_Master
            SET @count_mem=@count_mem+1
            WHERE regCode=@regCode
            IF(@regCode!=NULL)
            BEGIN
                UPDATE Registration_Master
                SET @count_mem=@count_mem+1
                WHERE sponcorid=@sponcorid AND count_mem=@count_mem
            END
        END

    END

END



SELECT     registrationid, regCode,  fname,mname,lname,username, p_password,question,answer, person_address, gender, sponcorid, dob,productname, payment, sponcorname, side, mobile, bankname, baccno, 
                      bankbranch, PAN, IFSC_code, email_id, member_status, count_mem,smart_pin,createddate, is_activate
FROM         Registration_Master

WHERE registrationid=@@IDENTITY
```